# Gist with custom ID

Tags: github, gist

Generally we give content to github API which in response gives user a gist with a unique ID. Is it possible to provide gist ID by user and then create a gist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [GitHub API on Gist](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/), the gist ID seems always generated by GitHub in response of [gist creation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/gists/gists?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-gist).

As a result, it doesn't seem to be customizable.

It might have been using a short SHA1 in 2014, but quickly used a longer SHA1 since then.